# Unable to return list of objects on form submission ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to store the form objects inside of an array of objects. But, I cannot get the objects to display in list form. I see one bullet point, being added, and then React complains about unique keys. I am using uuid for adding ids. How can I get the items to display that I'm adding with the reactjs form to show on the page? BTW: The for submits successfully, its getting the data to display on the page that's causing the problems.

**resume_react.jsx**

```
const jobExpList = []

 function App() {

    const [jobList, setjobList] = useState(jobExpList)

    const [jobExperience, setjobExperience] = useState({
        id: uuidv4(),
        jobCompanyName: '',
        jobDateStart: '',
        jobDateRangeEnd: '',
        jobDescription: ''
    });

    let handleJobExperienceChange = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = e.target.value;
        jobExperience[name] = value;
        setjobExperience(jobExperience);
    }

    let saveJobExperience = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(jobExperience);
        const newList = jobExpList.concat({ jobExperience, id: uuidv4()});
        setjobList(newList);

        setjobExperience({
            id: uuidv4(),
            jobCompanyName: '',
            jobDateStart: '',
            jobDateRangeEnd: '',
            jobDescription: ''
        });
    }
 }
```

**//list of objects
// displays one bullet point without contents of object & complains that key values have to be unique**

```
{Object.keys(jobList).map((item, i) => (
      <li key={i.key} style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.jobCompanyName}</li>
))}
```

**React Form / Functional**

```
     <form onSubmit={saveJobExperience}>
        <div className="pl-5 pr-5 pb-2">
           <div className="form-group">
           <label>Company Name</label>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Add Company Name" name="jobCompanyName" onChange={handleJobExperienceChange}  />
          </div>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col">
              <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Start Date</label>
                   <input type="date" className="form-control" placeholder={new Date().getFullYear() - 1} name="jobDateStart" onChange={handleJobExperienceChange} />
               </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
               <div className="form-group">
                    <label>End Date</label>
        <input type="date" className="form-control" placeholder={new Date().getFullYear()} name="jobDateRangeEnd" onChange={handleJobExperienceChange} />
               </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div className="pt-1">
          <div className="form-group">
              <label>Job Role/Responsibilities</label>
          <textarea style={{width: '100%'}} name="jobDescription" onChange={handleJobExperienceChange} />
         <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Add Job Experience</button>
          </div>
   </div>
    
 </div>
 </form>
```

// Correct approach

```
{jobList.map(item => (
       <li key={item.id} style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.jobExperience.jobCompanyName}</li>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{Object.keys(jobList).map((item, i) => (
            // i.key is undefined
      <li key={i.key} style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.jobCompanyName}</li>
))}
```

The variable `i` is the index of the current item which is of type `number`, so `i.key` is `undefined`. You are giving each item the key of `undefined`, so React is complaining that multiple items have the same key (they all have `undefined`).

You don't need to use Object.keys, as you want to map the actual items, not just the object keys, so remove `Object.keys`.

Your items already have unique `id`s, so use those, there is no need to use the item's index:

```
{jobList.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id} style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.jobCompanyName}</li>
))}
```

Comment: The object returns {id: "5e8d42ec-b7a9-4c0f-a9fc-0a34d6905947", jobCompanyName: "Borgs", jobDateStart: "2020-09-30", jobDateRangeEnd: "2020-10-01", jobDescription: ""} with console log. But, I still receive -- react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: Then your ids are not unique. Console log all of your objects' ids out and compare them to see if they are unique. If they are, then check other places in your app that you are using the `map` function. You may not be using unique keys somewhere else.

Comment: I got it. It was joblist.map(item => .....). I didn't need to use the Object.keys.